# how to rearrange chart positions based on parameter selection in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: ssrs-2008

i developed  some dash board reports which will display 15 reports in Dash Board . i provided one facility to the user to select required charts in dash board based on chart selection .

here issues is if user select only last 2 reports out of 15 Reports  then my dash board displaying free space for 13 Reports on dash board and selected reports are displaying in same page same position ..

now my requirement is if user selects required charts it should display from starting page without gap i.e only selected reports needs to display and other reports should not contain blank space in dash board.

it means free space should hide automatically based on chart selection i.e charts should re arranges its positions automaticllay

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: By empty space do you mean an empty table? Can you provide Screenshots?

Comment: Dear Frank , hanks for your reply, here user can select any report that time the report from available reports but always Report should display in first page even though the report is in 3 rd page.

Comment: I think this might help: right-click on each table, go to Tablix Properties, change the Visibility to "Show or hide based on an expression" and use the count of each tablix main dataset to hide it.